# Yahoo Gemini sandbox creation "INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS"

Tags: rest, yahoo-api

Trying to create a sandbox as described here:

https://developer.yahoo.com/gemini/guide/navigate-the-api/testing/

After trying all sorts of different things, I've ended up with the exact request from the docs:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://sandbox-api.gemini.yahoo.com/v2/rest/advertisersignup \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer nZ8hzgmc5...' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 03e2855d-3f5f-4780-a8f5-014f16bf1fac' \
  -d '{
   "advertiserName": "sandbox test"
}'
```

But I keep getting an "invalid email" error.

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "errIndex": -1,
            "code": "E40000_INVALID_INPUT",
            "message": "[INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS]",
            "description": ""
        }
    ],
    "response": {
        "advertiserName": "sandbox test"
    },
    "timestamp": "2018-07-30 22:08:07"
}
```

Am I missing something?